# Give me any package!

Tags: package-management

I'm running an older LTS version of Ubuntu and I cannot upgrade due to my VPS.

Given that, is there any way I can force apt-get to let me have access to all the newest packages from any repository anywhere?

...such that if I just type `apt-get install anyPackageIveEverHeardOf` it won't complain?

Note: this isn't asking to install all the packages, just to install any packages!

Comment: How much disk space do you got?

Comment: edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change the codename. then run `sudo apt-get update`, but be aware that **the system will now prompt you to install all the new package upgrades that would have been installed when you upgrade your install!**

Comment: This would require a search service of some kind that indexes “any repository anywhere”, which I doubt exists. (No, Google doesn't solve the problem: too many false positives.) In any case, a lot of these packages would be uninstallable because they are intended for different distributions or different Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. you can download any required package & can install it.
Either you can download it from web or like,

```
$ sudo apt-get download [packagename]
```

or

you can specify the web URL and can download it from terminal using wget like,

```
$ sudo wget [http:\\exampl.com\pack.deb]
```

then you can install that .deb file as,

```
$ dpkg -i [packagename]
```

Comment: This doesn't help to find packages from “any repository anywhere”.

Comment: If you want to find new packages from repository, simply open the update-manager in ubuntu, & you will get a list of all packages that are new or not installed on your machine & then you can install required packages to your machine.

Comment: That's packages from repositories that are already in your source list. This is not what the question is about.